# Password Reset using Mac OS X install media

Tags: imac

I forgot my password for my imac. If I reset my password using the Mac OS X install media, will I loose all data stored in my computer?

Answer (score 2):

No you will not, resetting your password using the installation media will leave all data intact. However if you are using Filevault you would need your password or the recovery key to access any encrypted data.

Comment: You also will lose access to other passwords which are stored in the keychain.  When you first log in with the new (reset) password, there will be a warning to that effect; and you can create a new login keychain.  The old keychain will still be saved, in case you ever remember your old password.